# How to get an Express static file server to handle Windows backslashes correctly?

Tags: node.js, express

I've written a vanilla server (using Node.js and Express) to browse files and directories (based off the [directory](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/directory.js) middleware). On a Windows machine, it gets confused by the backslashes, and quickly breaks by providing invalid/broken links as you navigate -- links becomes a soup of forward and backslashes, with dir names incorrectly repeated over and over in them, etc.

So or example, going to localhost:8888, clicking on 'lib' folder, then '..', gives me:

```
/ \lib / \\lib\..\ /
```

Here's the code.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
server.configure(function(){
    server.use(express.static('./stuff'));
    server.use(express.directory('./stuff'));
});
server.listen(8888);
```

What do I need to do to get this to work on a Windows machine?

Comment: Which version of windows do you use? I use Windows 8 and it works for me.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Enterprise SP1, Node 0.10.12, Express 3.2.6, Connect 2.7.11

Comment: Looking at the [history](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/commits/master/lib/middleware/directory.js) of the `directory.js`, it seems that there was a change that might have broken the path generation on Windows. Can you please post here your version of lines 176-180 of the following file: `connect/lib/middleware/directory.js`?

Comment: Here they are:    return '<li><a href="'
      + join(dir, file)
      + '" class="'
      + classes.join(' ') + '"'
      + ' title="' + file + '">'

Comment: @verybadalloc, thanks -- you basically have provided the answer, indirectly. I've changed line 176 to:  + join(dir, file).replace(/\\/g, '/')

Comment: Glad I could help. What's more interesting is to be able to share the fix with the community. @user568109 can you please tell us what version of Connect you have. We might need to make a pull request to fix this.

Comment: 2.7.11 although directory.js looks unchanged as of today's 2.8.0 release

Comment: mine is node 0.10.5 express 3.1.0 connect 2.7.2. Looking at history the corrected code was reverted, maybe it caused problems.

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to add some more testing to the directory middleware: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/test/directory.js, what's currently there doesn't seem very thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@verybadalloc and @user2524973 found a bug in the express directory.js middleware that caused this problem. In the comments to the original question they also provided a fix.

Find the lines that says

```
return '<li><a href="' + join(dir, file) + '" class="' + classes.join(' ') + '"' + ' title="' + file + '">'
```

It should be around line number 176. Change it to:

```
return '<li><a href="' + join(dir, file).replace(/\\/g, '/') + '" class="' + classes.join(' ') + '"' + ' title="' + file + '">'
```

... and it should work better on Windows.

It seems like this fix was added to the main repository, but later removed, so this fix might have some unforeseen consequence? Works for me anyway, I'm just using it to list my music folder.

I posted this answer since I almost missed that they had solved it in the comments. Thanks.